# Photoshop: knockout layer through parent groups

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I know there are two options for knockouts: deep and shallow. However, I want something sort of in between.

I'm creating a UI, so there are a lot of a elements/layers going on and I like to keep them all organized on groups. However, that messes up how layers knockout each other (understandably).

I don't want to use knockout: deep because I don't want layers to cut through *everything*, but knockout: shallow doesn't traverse up through parent groups and therefore doesn't create the desired effect.

Is there a way for knockouts to go through some groups, but them stop at a specified layer and knockout *only* up to that?

Right now, I'm having to leave layers ungrouped so they knockout correctly.

**Edit:** Here is the effect I'm going for (the (+) button knocks out the dark overlay to the image behind it):

[image]

And here's how I currently have to arrange the layers:

[image]

Notice how I have to leave the `Add button: +` and `Add button: border` layers ungrouped so they can knockout the `BG` layer (which then passes through to the `Wallpapers` group). Ideally, I'd like similar layers like that to be grouped for my own sanity...

**Edit 2:** Here are more screenshots. The first is the desired effect (knocking out the `BG` layer to the `Wallpaper` group. The second is simply just having the button be white with reduced opacity. I know that I could just make the shape red in this example, but I wanted to clearly show the different results between the two methods. It would not work for anything that's not a solid color.

[image] [image]

Comment: Can you add more context and perhaps a screenshot? What are you using the knockout options for? What effect are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Sure, please see my edits.

Comment: I guess I'm still confused why you are using knockouts instead of just making the add symbol and circle a white shape layer with (as it looks in your screenshot) 80-95% opacity?

Comment: I basically want it to appear as though it's cutting through the dark overlay. It may not be obvious in that screenshot (and it does still have a bit of white to the shape). For example, if the `Wallpaper` group is purple, I want the (+) button to be purple. If it's yellow, I want the button to be yellow. I don't want to have to manually change the colors of the button if the `Wallpaper` changes (plus if it's not a flat color, it won't look like it's "cutting through").

Comment: Please see additional screenshots comparing the two methods.

Answer (score 1):

One option I can think for you to do here is using a vector mask on your `BG` layer.

Answer (score 0):

Well as it turns out, you can apply a knockout to an entire group itself, so all of its content knocks out the parent content. I didn't think of that.

In this case, I can group the `Add button: +` and `Add button: border` layers into a group, and apply knockout: shallow to that group.

This only works if you want *every* layer in the group to knock out, obviously, and still only affects the nearest parent group. If you don't want some layers to knock out, it seems you'll have to group them separately (which makes sense from a graphical perspective - I was wanting to group layers mostly for organizational needs).